# Why is autocorrection causing NaN warnings on a simple TextField?

Tags: swiftui, textfield

Whenever autocorrection highlights characters to offer corrections, I get the warning `"Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem."`, about six times.

Adding `.autocorrectionDisabled()` prevents the warning but obviously impacts the user experience.

This occurs both on the simulator and a physical iPhone. I'm running Xcode 15.2 and iOS 17.2.1

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var text = ""

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("Label", text: $text)
        .padding()
        .border(Color.gray)
    }
    .padding()
  }
}
```

Also when the text field goes into focus the first time on the simulator, I get the warning `"Error for queryMetaDataSync: 2"` twice, and when it goes into focus thereafter I get `"-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID"`.

Why are all these warnings triggered?

Edit:
On iOS 16 I still get errors when text is highlighted for autocorrection:

```
2024-02-11 23:52:08.244121-0800 TextFieldAutoCorrectionBug[12129:222799] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600002395ea0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2024-02-11 23:52:08.355592-0800 TextFieldAutoCorrectionBug[12129:222799]  HALC_ProxyObjectMap::_CopyObjectByObjectID: failed to create the local object
2024-02-11 23:52:08.355753-0800 TextFieldAutoCorrectionBug[12129:222799]  HALC_ShellDevice::RebuildControlList: couldn't find the control object
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue, all works well for me in my tests. On MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews). 
 If it was a bug in Xcode 15.2 and iOS 17.2.1, it seems to have disappeared in the latest.
 
 Note you should use `@State private var text = ""`

Comment: Weird. And yeah, I use `private` in production code, but thanks